# PHP use only works when I change a filename

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a class that I'm trying to import, it's called "AmericanPhone" (it's for validating American phone numbers), and it's under the namespace `ShinePHP\Data`. When I try and import the class like this:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
use ShinePHP\Data\AmericanPhone;
```

It gives me the following error:

`Uncaught Error: Class 'ShinePHP\Data\AmericanPhone' not found`

I know the package is autoloading correctly because I'm using other classes from that same package.

I then found something.....the name of the file that holds the "AmericanPhone" class is called `PhoneValidator.php` when I change the name of that file to `AmericanPhone.php` the autoload works and I'm able to use the class. So my question is:

**How can I get the file to be usable without changing the name of the file in question?**

Comment: Do you run `composer dump-autoload` when you make changes? Is it a custom class or some third-party library?

Comment: 1. Yes, just ran it, no change. Again, not an autoload problem, because I can change the classname and it works just fine, and other classes I'm using with the library work fine as well. 2. Third party library

Comment: according to PSR-4, the filename should be named after the classname : https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Comment: Thank you, Pierre. I had overlooked that simple detail. Composer implements PSR-4. If you don't follow such standard, you need your own arrangements. [Mcgurk-Adam /
ShinePHP](https://github.com/Mcgurk-Adam/ShinePHP/blob/master/composer.json) claims so but I feel it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you both. I would be happy to mark one of your answers as correct if you add it!

Comment: But it's strange because it's a library with 1480 installs and no bug reports about this. I wouldn't discard it's working by pure chance. If you first attempt to use the class that gives name to the file, further unreachable classes are already loaded.